# Texture rendering appears Dull (openGL ES 2.0 iOS)

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0, shader, textures

Ive just started with openGLES2.0 on iOS and im trying to render a texture onto screen.

The problem is that the texture appears different (dull and almost monochromatic) as compared to the real image it is supposed to render. In a sense the true colors of the texture image isnt reflected while rendering using openGL

The shader program is quite simple:

Fragment Shader

```
varying lowp vec4 DestinationColor;
varying lowp vec2 TexCoordOut; 
uniform sampler2D Texture; 

void main(void) {
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(Texture, TexCoordOut); 
}
```

Vertex Shader

```
attribute vec4 Position; 


uniform mat4 Projection;
uniform mat4 Modelview;

attribute vec2 TexCoordIn;
varying vec2 TexCoordOut; 

void main(void) { 

    gl_Position = Projection * Modelview * Position;
    TexCoordOut = TexCoordIn;
}
```

The same texturing worked fine on openGL ES 1.0, with the colors showing up correctly!

EDIT:

OpenGL context setup Code:

```
- (void)setupContext {   
    EAGLRenderingAPI api = kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2;
    _context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:api];

    if (!_context) {
        DLog(@"Failed to initialize OpenGLES 2.0 context");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (![EAGLContext setCurrentContext:_context]) {
        DLog(@"Failed to set current OpenGL context");
        exit(1);
     }
}
```

Texture Loading Code:

```
- (GLuint)setupTexture:(UIImage *)image {
    glGenTextures(1, &Texture1);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, Texture1);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);

    GLuint width = CGImageGetWidth(image.CGImage);
    GLuint height = CGImageGetHeight(image.CGImage);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    void *imageData = malloc( height * width * 4 );
    CGContextRef imgContext = CGBitmapContextCreate( imageData, width, height, 8, 4 *   width, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big );
    CGContextTranslateCTM (imgContext, 0, height);
    CGContextScaleCTM (imgContext, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextSetBlendMode(imgContext, kCGBlendModeCopy);
    CGColorSpaceRelease( colorSpace );
    CGContextClearRect( imgContext, CGRectMake( 0, 0, width, height ) );
    CGContextTranslateCTM( imgContext, 0, height - height );
    CGContextDrawImage( imgContext, CGRectMake( 0, 0, width, height ), image.CGImage );

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageData);

    CGContextRelease(imgContext);

    free(imageData);

return Texture1;
```

}

SECOND EDIT:
Layer Setup

```
 - (void)setupLayer {
    _eaglLayer = (CAEAGLLayer*) self.layer;
    _eaglLayer.opaque = YES;
    _eaglLayer.drawableProperties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO],  kEAGLDrawablePropertyRetainedBacking, kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8, kEAGLDrawablePropertyColorFormat, nil];

 }
```

Ive added this piece code to the layer setup. Still no luck!

Comment: You might want to show the code you use to load the image and upload the texture, as well as how you set up your EAGLContext.

Answer (score 1):

To preserve colors you should initialize OpenGL with 24 or 32 bit color (request config with *888 RGB* instead of *565* configs). Also you should use 8-bit per channel textures.

Does resulting image has some green tint? This is the most noticeable color distortion in 16-bit color.

Comment: Ive added the code in the question to show how i have setup my EAGL context. How do i request config with 888 RGB here?

Comment: Ive added a piece of code following your suggestion while setting up the layer. It still doesn't work! Any idea what might be going wrong?

Comment: And no green tint. Just ends up monochrome!